# Jquery validation is not working with a select element

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-validate

I have a form that is validate with jquery validation, that works properly for all fields beside of a select input.

This is my html (with Razor)

```
 <select id="properties" name="properties" class="required form-control">
     <option value="">Select a Property</option>
     @foreach (var item in Model.Properties)
     {
        <option value="@item.Name">
            @item.Name
        </option>
     }
 </select>
```

And my jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $("#properties").on("change", function () {
       $("#propertyName").val($(this).val());
    });

    $("#form").validate();
    $.extend($.validator.messages, { required: "*", email: "Invalid email address." });
});
```

I set the first line with an empty value but it didn't help!

I can't see any reason for this to not working, please advise.

Comment: Not the answer but, You have two nested *document ready handlers*.

Comment: You are right, I removed it, thank you.

Comment: i may be blind - but i don't see an item with the id propertyName, you are adressing with your selector within the on("change") function...

Comment: That is not really the HTML, that is the Razor markup.  Instead of the view code, you should have shown us the relevant ***rendered*** HTML of the `select` element including the surrounding `form` tags.  After all, JavaScript can only see what the browser has rendered, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @errand's comment I found the answer!

I was looking at my code in order to post the rest of the fields and I noticed that the `<select>` element was outside of the `<form>`, so the validation for this element was never triggered!

Thank you!